# ibase_execute update returns false with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, firebird, php-7.2

There is a script which connects to a remote firebird database, fetch some data, manipulate and stores it back.

```
$dbh = ibase_connect('1.1.1.1:D:\\db.gdb','user','pass');   
$q = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE P1 = ".$p1." AND P2 = ".(int)$p2;
$sth = ibase_query($dbh, $q);
...
$query = ibase_prepare($dbh, "UPDATE MYTABLE SET FOO = ? WHERE P1 = ? AND P2 = ?");
if( !ibase_execute($query, $newdata, $p1, $p2) ) echo 'store issue';
```

This code works with PHP 5.6, there's no issue. But when I switch to PHP 7.2, the fetching part does work, but the UPDATE shows the issue message.
What should I change there?

Comment: Have you tried checking the [error message](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-errmsg.php)?

Comment: maybe try to peep in between PHP and Firebird using http://fbprofiler.sf.net

Comment: Thank you for suggesting ibase_errmsg(), there was some typing error. I changed the code from parameter binding to a direct query and got no error.

Comment: "direct query" splcing is fragile, both against malicious users and data types errors. Nor everytype has clear "string literal" form that is easy to construct (without making your program a mess) and which works regardless of OS localization. And no, it would not require travelling to see different localization, it would be anough for one user with different ethnicity tuning his Windows/Linux workstaiton to his liking. So you better go the different way and change BOTH queries to using parameters. And maybe starty using PDO or some other generic library.